Расчет качества видео
Есть множество видеофайлов.
У каждого своя высота кадра, свой битрейт, кодек и прочее. Есть видео, высота кадра 1080, а визуально по качеству оно 480...
Необходимо для каждого видео, определить в какие качества его возможно привести
144р
240р
360р
480р
720р
1080р
1440р
2160р

В данный момент, чтобы определить в какие разрешения преобразовывать видео, ориентируюсь на высоту кадра + битрейт. Что не верно...
Поскольку как ранее писал, высота кадра может быть 1080, а по качеству картинки оно на 480. Так же битрейт и качество может различаться, в зависимости от кодека. Некоторые кодеки лучше сжимают, меньший битрейт при этом качество не теряется...
Вопрос в том, что за формула, на что смотреть на входной файл. Чтобы определить в какие качество допустимо преобразовывать?

Не бывает такой формулы, плюс вы смешиваете разные понятия, 1080p обозначает ТОЛЬКО размер картинки (и развёртку) и к качеству не имеет никакого отношения

Да, высота кадра. Как определять качество видео, вопрос актуален...

Только сравнением с эталонным видео в оригинальном качестве

Скорее всего надо квадраты искать в нём.

@Qwertiy и эта идея обломается об видео, автор которого специально добавил квадраты как авторскую задумку

@andreymal, ну авторские квадраты будут отличаться по распределению цветов. Ну и они ж не на протяжении всего видео будут. Тут экспериментировать надо.

@Qwertiy мы не можем знать все возможные задумки всех возможных авторов

@andreymal, ну парочке невезучих авторов не повезёт. Может ещё белому шуму не повезти, наверное, хотя, ему наоборот хорошо должно быть, наверное.

Что за эталонное видео в оригинальном качестве?

То, которое послужило источником для кодека

Не понимаю... Есть входное видео которое необходимо преобразовать в различные качества. Как определить что входное видео допустимо преобразовать в 1/2/3 качество... Вопрос актуален

Эталонное видео это не то, что преобразовываем? Это та, которое использовали при создании кодека?

Сейчас экспериментирую с кодеком libaom-av1, затем буду смотреть на vvc. Где для них найти эталонное видео?

«Есть входное видео» — откуда оно взялось?

«определить что входное видео допустимо преобразовать» — можно сразу сказать что недопустимо, потому что ЛЮБОЕ преобразование не-lossless кодеком испортит качество

Чтобы определить, в какое качество можно пожать видео, необходимо, как ни странно, пожать видео в это качество, затем картинку апскелить обратно и сравнить с картинкой из непожатого видео. Например, если видео было апскейлом с низкого разрешения или просто плохого качества, то после описанной операции разница будет небольшая, а если оно было высокого качества, то разница будет большой. Параметры допустимого падения качеcтва устанавливаете опытным путем.

Что то интересное, но не совсем понятно. Берем кадр 1000x1000p, уменьшаем в двое, затем возвращаем к размерам... Что значит апскелить? Может есть модуль на пайтоне, который посмотрит на кадры и выдаст значение чего то, размытость или плотность пикселей. Зная этот параметр, смотрим на размер кадра и готово...

@flex Берете кусок из видео 2160р, кодируете его в 720р, потом кадр из полученного видео маштабируете обратно до 2160p и сравниваете с этим же кадром из исходного видео для оценки потери детализации.

Есть VMAF к ffmpeg, меняем битрейт, оставляем размеры и частоту кадров тойже. Сравниваем, получаем % схожести в качестве. Только что это даст? Знаем процент схожести с оригиналом, как это поможет перед тем как определить в какое качество возможно видео конвектировать 144/240/360/480/720/1080/1440/2160... Остается только смотреть на размер кадра, больше никак?

@flex Если процент схожести достаточно высокий, то делается вывод, что кодировать в 720р можно.

Берем кадр 2160, уменьшаем до высоты 144, затем из 144 делаем 2160. Получаем схожесть 1%, делаем вывод что качество 2160 преобразовывать в 144 не стоит.  Не выход так делать...

@flex Ну а если схожесть будет процентов 90, то делаем вывод, что для этого ролика и 144 сойдет.

Не знаю, нужно будет попробовать.

И так понятно, что из меньшего кадра делая большее. Теряется качество, будет все размыто. Что тут сравнивать, 2160 детальное изображение. И изображение которое увеличили 20, которое из себя представляет кляксы... Тут не будет никакой схожести...

@flex "И так понятно, что из меньшего кадра делая большее. Теряется качество, будет все размыто. Что тут сравнивать, 2160 детальное изображение." - вы ошибаетесь. Делая из меньшего кадра больше качество не теряется. И оно может не теряться даже если наоборот, делать из большего меньшее в том случае, если качество изначально было плохим.

Спс, буду пробовать тогда
